# Eclipse SWT Error : Could not find a menu within the shell 'Shell with text {Shell {C/C++ - Eclipse SDK}}

Tags: eclipse, swtbot

I work actualy in a swtbot test of a plugin. When i want to upgrade Juno to Luna.
After passing in Luna version all tests passed. Or now I have an error at this line :

```
bot.menu("Window").menu("Preferences").click();
```

that result this error :

```
 org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.exceptions.WidgetNotFoundException: Could not find a menu within the shell 'Shell with text {Shell {C/C++ - Eclipse SDK}}'
```

Have you an idea .

Thank's per advance.

Comment: Any news on this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes. actions set is decrepted in plugin.xml replace by new way to solve.